# filter/search grid using combobox extjs mvc

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc

I have a comboBox in which items are coming from database and a have applied filter option using that comboBox...Combo works good at first time ,but the problem is when i want to select items from the comboBox at second time i don't find items in my combo(only the previous selected item)..

```
this.control({
                    'combobox[itemId=YourCombo]':
                    {
                    select: this.combogridfilter
                    }
                    });       

combogridfilter: function(newValue){
    var value1= Ext.getCmp('myCombo').getValue();
        var grid=Ext.getCmp('afteraddingtemplate');
            grid.store.load().filter([
                {id:'item_code', property:"item_code", value: value1, anyMatch: false}
            ]);

    },
```

here is the combo configuration

```
xtype:'combo',
            id:'myCombo',
            itemId:'YourCombo',
            action:'change',
            fieldLabel:'Select a template',
            queryMode:'local',
            store:this.store,
            name:'item_code',
            displayField:'item_code',
            valueField:'item_code',
            enableKeyEvents: true,
            typeAhead: true,
            mode: 'local',
            forceSelection: true,
            triggerAction: 'all',
            emptyText: 'Select a Template',
            selectOnFocus: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clear filter before applicate a new one:

```
combogridfilter: function(newValue){
var value1= Ext.getCmp('myCombo').getValue();
    var grid=Ext.getCmp('afteraddingtemplate');
        grid.store.clearFilter(true);
        grid.store.filter('item_code', value1);
},
```

Comment: solved some issue,but combo not showing  all the items when going to select second time...

Comment: the grid store and the combo store aren't the same?

Comment: That's why the combo store is filtered also. Try to create an instance of the store, to the combobox like this:  
`xtype:'combo',  
store: Ext.create('your_store'),...`

Answer (score 1):

You should not share the store between the grid and the combo. Sharing stores between components is asking for trouble. What is happening, is that when you filter the grid, you filter the combo too. Given it's the same store...

What you can do is use a simple memory store for your combo, that you populate when the grid store is loaded.

For example, configure your combo this way:

```
{
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    xtype:'combo',
    id:'myCombo',
    itemId:'YourCombo',
    action:'change',
    fieldLabel:'Select a template',
    queryMode:'local',
    store: {
        fields: ['item_code']
        ,proxy: {type: 'memory', reader: 'array'}
    },
    name:'item_code',
    displayField:'item_code',
    valueField:'item_code',
    enableKeyEvents: true,
    typeAhead: true,
    mode: 'local',
    forceSelection: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    emptyText: 'Select a Template',
    selectOnFocus: true 
}
```

And populate it on the `load` event of the grid store:

```
grid.getStore().on('load', function(store) {
    Ext.getCmp('myCombo').getStore().loadData(store.getRange());
});
```

Comment: where is the load event of grid store, i simply set store as...store:'storeName'

Comment: There's many places you can catch this event. The `control` method of your controller seems to be a good one.

Comment: thanks for knowledge sharing..I have changed the combo and grid store and made them different and that's what i have to